# Height:100% when inside an ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

So I set

### .scroll {height:100%};

and now when I set div height to 100% it covers the entire screen like it should...except when I put the div inside an ng-repeat.

This does not work:

```
 <div ng-repeat="m in diff">
        <div ng-if="meal_index==$index" ng-init="vs(m.time);tracker(m.time);keepimg(m.img);">
            <div style="height:80%;width:100%;max-width:600px;border-radius:100px;border:2px solid black;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
                <img src="{{m.img}}" style="width:100%;height:100%;"/>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Now the image (m.img) does not cover the entire screen like it should

Thanks for the help in advance :)

Answer (score -1):

Ehhh it's easy for me!

```
<div ng-repeat="m in diff">
        <div ng-if="meal_index==$index" ng-init="vs(m.time);tracker(m.time);keepimg(m.img);">
            <div style="height:8031231232131232%;width:100%;max-width:600px;border-radius:100px;border:2px solid black;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
                <img src="{{m.img}}" style="width:100%;height:100%;"/>
    cout << IMG
    cin >> img 
cout << "It's my img" << img;
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: uhhh I'm confused...what?!